# Asana StatusCode=404

Tags: json, apex-code, asana

Writing a wrapper class for Asana API in Salesforce APEX, encountering this status code for any 'valid' GET command sent:

```
HttpResponse[Status=Object Not Found, StatusCode=404]
```

Even with the simplest of commands, GET /users/me

This is the HttpRequest that is generated and sent:

```
System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me, Method=GET]
```

Comment: Are you authenticated?

Comment: yep - using basic authentication as described here: http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#api_keys

Comment: This works in general. I'm unfamiliar with APEX, do you have any visibility into the full request that's actually being sent? A GET request to that URL will work (try it with curl, per the doc examples) so there must be something the underlying library is doing you're not expecting.

Comment: Have you added site to Remote Sites? Have you got any error from Apex code?

Comment: Yes Asana is added to Remote sites.

Comment: And I was getting an Apex code error, as it wasn't expecting null response from this query but that is handled now but still getting same 404 status code